# How can I find if a given integer value of n digits contains a particular digit in less than linear time?

Tags: java, algorithm, search, optimization

I could only think of ways in which you would need to check each digit of the input value at least once to search for the digit.

As I understand, converting into string and using inbuilt functions like ".contains()" takes even longer.

Is there some algorithm or optimization that I can use to know if a particular digit is contained in the integer value in less than linear time with reference to number of digits in the value?

The input value may have as many as a hundred thousand digits.

**Update:** I have to work on 15 separate queries, each having one large integer of less than 10^6 digits(generated randomly), I have to determine if this value contains a particular digit(and keep a count upto 2 occurances,anything more can be ignored).
I wish to know if there is a way to perform this act of "digit-searching" in the integer value in less than linear time.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't. Is there any reason you need sublinear time?

Comment: @Debabrata n lies between 1 and 100000 and yes.

Comment: @Allen O(n) is not fast enough :(

Comment: Well, you obviously don't need to check each digit at least once. You need to check each digit, once and only once, and you can stop as soon as you found the one you searched. This is till O(n), but for a value containing one hundred thousand digits, the probability of stopping after just a few ones is very very high. What are those numbers? What's their type? What do they represent? Where do they come from? How are they distributed?

Comment: Why would O(n) not be fast enough? Are you making multiple queries? (there are only 10 unique queries that you can make for denary - or whichever base you are using)

Comment: @Cyka Then maybe you should look for a different way to solve your problem, which does not involve this search. What is your larger goal here? It's also possible that your implementation is particularly inefficient or that the bottleneck is actually in a different area of your code, in which case codereview.stackexchange.com could help.

Comment: With the sparse information you provided it's fairly impossible to come up with an answer. If you want to have this addressed I suggest you update your question with at least some examples.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog  


Updated the question.

Comment: @yacc updated the question.

Comment: @JBNizet updated the question.

Comment: You still didn't say what constitutes a digit for you. :) Oh, and regarding linear time O(N), what is N here?

Comment: @yacc , digit meaning 0-9 and N is the number if digits in each query(which has an upper limit of 10^6).

Comment: so now the picture gets much clearer... how is the data stored, as a byte string?

Comment: I think you're preoptimizing. If the digits are generated randomly, then finding a specific digit should be very fast, because the probability of not finding the digit among the first few ones is very low. or example, the probability of not finding your digit in the first 100 digits is 0,000027 (9^100/10^100)

Comment: This could be reduced to the problem where an unordered set contains a certain element. You can't solve that without looking at the whole set.

Comment: @yacc Input data is stored as a BigInteger value.

Comment: You could generate a sort of histogram when you create a number, or calculate it offline, and keep it in the database. So later you pull your information from the histograms. Like how many 0s, how many 1s etc are in the number.

Comment: To my knowledge, any method of determining if a number contains a digit will be linear in the number of digits. However, you say that you have 15 queries, each of which contains a very large number. If those 15 queries are fixed and the number doesn't change, could you pre-process the data and use a lookup table during queries?

Comment: If it's a question of time complexity, couldn't you distribute the job among several CPUs, each one taking a chunk of the number, working in parallel?

Comment: @Assafs unfortunately that's not an option. :(

Comment: @JimMischel I do not know what those 15 queries are(but they are fixed,yes). Execution happens behind the scenes, and all I am made aware of is whether my code performs the task correctly in a given time.

Comment: I get the idea that you're asking the wrong question. Do you *really* need to determine if a 100000-digit number contains a particular digit, or are you just thinking that doing so would help you solve the larger problem more efficiently? What is the larger problem you're trying to solve?